# Como fazer para que uma página do meu site apareça no mesmo dia nos resultados de busca do google?

Tags: seo, html-meta-tag

Preciso conhecer uma maneira de uma página do meu site aparecer nos resultados de busca do google no mesmo dia.

Alguma sugestão sobre o que é preciso fazer? Pois percebo que há sites que uma vez que uma notícia é publicada em poucos minutos já está nos resultados de busca.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem algumas coisas que você pode fazer:

1. Crie um [sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=pt), onde você pode informar a estrutura do site e a frequência com que cada página é atualizada. Isso não garante a indexação constante, mas dá uma "dica" ao robô indexador do Google.
2. Mantenha a estrutura do site organizada e um código limpo. Quanto mais o HTML estiver dentro do padrão esperado pelos buscadores, melhor.
3. Crie conteúdo bom, com tamanho razoável e não copiado de outro site, e que seja linkado por outros sites (sem formar uma rede fechada de referências). O indexador do Google leva em conta todas essas coisas.

O algoritmo do Google identifica várias características do site, então é complicado tentar enganá-lo. Se você colocar lá no *sitemap* que a página muda a cada hora e na verdade ela muda uma vez por dia ele vai saber disso.

Além disso, páginas com *ranking* mais elevado (vários links para o site, conteúdo bom) são indexados com mais frequência.

Otimização para buscadores é uma arte e uma profissão em si. Pode demandar um bom trabalho, dependendo do que você tem em mãos.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi dito, **é importante criar um Sitemap (mapa do site) para organizar e listar os URLs das páginas do site**.

Mas o que é que isto significa na prática?

Basicamente, **ao utilizar um Sitemap XML estamos a ajudar o Google a indexar o nosso site mais facilmente**.

Ora, isto vai permitir que todas aquelas páginas que estão no *"fundo do nosso site"* e são díficeis de aceder posssam também elas ser indexadas e aparecer nos resultados de pesquisa do Google.

Mas como criamos um Sitemap?

**Esta é a parte mais fácil uma vez que é possível **[criar um sitemap em menos de 1 minuto](http://nelsondias.net/guia-pratico-para-criar-sitemap-seo-em-menos-de-1-minuto/)**.**

Resumidamente, existem duas formas de criar o Sitemap:

1. **Tenho um site Wordpress:** Basta instalar e ativar o plugin **YOAST SEO**, aceder a "**SEO**" > "***Features***” e ativar a opção “***Advanced settings pages***”.
   O Sitemap é criado automaticamente e pode ser acedido em "**XML Sitemaps**" por baixo de "**SEO**" na barra lateral do lado esquerdo.
2. **Não tenho um site Wordpress**: Entrar no site **XML-Sitemaps**.
     A partir do **domínio do site**, e da definição de alguns parâmetros tais como a **frequência com que o conteúdo da página é atualizado** e o grau de **importância que queremos dar às páginas do site**, é possível criar o sitemap do site rapidamente.

No entanto, um Sitemap por si só vale zero.

Para que um Sitemap seja útil, o primeiro passo é indexar o site no Google com o auxílio do Search Console (ferramenta grátis do Google).

**Quais as vantagens do Google Search Console?**

A partir do momento que o seu site é verificado com sucesso no Google Search Console, existem várias funcionalidades que vão ficar à sua disposição.

- **Uma delas é fazer o upload do Sitemap criado**, indo a "**Crawl**" no lado esquerdo > "Sitemaps", podemos adicionar o caminho onde está o nosso sitemap.
  Nota: Antes de submeter o sitemap, faça o Teste para confirmar que está tudo bem.
- Outra, é ter a hipótese de **[pedir ao Google para indexar um url no mesmo dia](http://nelsondias.net/google-search-console-como-indexar-site-no-google/)**.

Para tal, basta aceder a "**Crawl**" no lado esquerdo > "**Fetch as Google**" e indicar o caminho do url que quer indexar imediatamente.

Esta funcionalidade é extremamente útil considerando que que, em média, um site demora cerca de 4 dias a 4 semanas a ser indexado organicamente pelo Google.

**No entanto, esta funcionalidade está limitada a 500 pedidos por mês.**

**Portanto, a melhor sugestão é mesmo na altura da criação do sitemap XML indicar ao bots do Google que gostaría que o seu site fosse atualizado nos resultados de pesquisa mais regularmente.**
Por exemplo: frequência de atualização diária ou semanal.